# ROS2 - Humble - ros2_control Possible to use position and velocity forward controller at same time?

Tags: control, ros-humble, ros2-control, ros2-controllers

Is it possible to spawn and use both a forward position controller and a forward velocity controller at the same time? My hardware interface supports torque, speed, and position (feedforward PID underneath) and I'd like to specify both speed and position targets without having to write a custom controller. Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, generally speaking this is possible. But then you have two topics for the commands.

I'd consider merging `velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController` with a `position_controllers/JointGroupPositionController` into a custom one, where you use [JointTrajectory](https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/blob/rolling/trajectory_msgs/msg/JointTrajectory.msg) as command topic.